# https.request to wikipedia page - not found error.

Tags: javascript, node.js, https, request

In this code  I want to create a request object to download a wikipedia page.

This is how  I tried to do it:

```
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
     hostname: 'en.wikipedia.org/',
     port: 443,
     path: '/wiki/George_Washington'
};

var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
    var responseBody = "";
    res.setEncoding("UTF-8");
    res.on('data', function(chunk) {
       responseBody += chunk;
    });
    res.on('end', function() {

        fs.writeFile('wikipedia.md', responseBody, function(err) {
            if(err) {
                 throw err;
            }
        });

    });
 });

req.on('error', function(err) {
    if(err) {
        console.log('Problem with request ', err);
}
});
req.end();
```

But i received the following error:

```
Problem with request  { [Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND en.wikipedia.org/ en.wikipedia.org/:443]
 code: 'ENOTFOUND',
 errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
 syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
 hostname: 'en.wikipedia.org/',
 host: 'en.wikipedia.org/',
 port: 443 }
```

Could it be that I got the wrong port number? Or somthing is wrong with my routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hostname:

```
hostname: 'en.wikipedia.org/',
```

contains a trailing slash. Remove it:

```
hostname: 'en.wikipedia.org',
```

and your code works fine.